# "Unable to register(....) " error in rpc when running without sudo

Tags: rpc

I have written a simple "rpc" program. 
Generated all the files with rpcgen -a -C abc.x
But when I am trying to run abc_server I am getting 
unable to register(PROG,PROG1,udp)... PROG is program name and PROG! is version.

How can i run it without sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the issue is that generally a program that is not running as root may not bind to ports numbered less than 1024.  If that's the case, then solutions may include

- using port numbers higher than 1024
- on Linux, you can allow a specific binary to open such privileged ports:

  ```
  setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' <path-to-binary>
  ```